Prime powers; are there more powers of 2, or powers of higher primes, smaller than N?
Given the set https://oeis.org/A025475 with the prime powers, excluding the primes themselves. Let's define two subsets of A025475.
$A=\{4,8,16,32,\dots\}$, with all powers of 2 ($2^k, k>1$) smaller than $N$. And
$B=\{1,9,25,27,49,\dots\}$ with all the other powers ($p^k, k=0$ or $k>1$, $p$ is a prime larger than 2) smaller than $N$.
I'm interested in de cardinality of $A$ and $B$. It's easy to see, that there are more elements in $B$ than there are in $A$, for, let's say $N=1.000$. In this case $|A| = 8$ and $|B|=18$.
But, is $|B|>|A|$ true for all values $N>1.000$? Intuitively not, but I can't prove it

Since $B$ contains all squares of primes, it will have at least $\pi(\sqrt N) \sim 2\sqrt N/\log N$ elements up to $N$, which is far larger than the $\sim (\log N)/\log 2$ powers of $2$ up to $N$.

For all $N \gt 1000$, we have $\lvert B\rvert \gt \lvert A\rvert$. Consider that $\lvert A\rvert = m - 1$ whenever $2^{m} \lt N \le 2^{m+1}$ for any positive integer $m$. Let $m \ge 10$, and note for the inequality to always be  true it's sufficient to show for all larger $m$ that there is at least one prime $p$ between $2^{\frac{m}{2}}$ and $2^{\frac{m+1}{2}} = \sqrt{2}\left(2^{\frac{m}{2}}\right)$, since then $2^{m} \lt p^2 \lt 2^{m+1}$ means there's always at least add one more element in the set $B$ for each increase in $m$.
The Better Results section of Wikipedia's "Bertrand's postulate" article states

In $1952$, Jitsuro Nagura proved that for $n\ge 25$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $\left(1 + \frac{1}{5}\right)n$. 10

Note that $25 \lt 2^{\frac{10}{2}} = 32$, and $1.2 \lt \sqrt{2}$. Thus, Nagura's result applies, so there's always at least one prime $p$ between $2^{\frac{m}{2}}$ and $2^{\frac{m+1}{2}}$ for each $m \ge 10$. This means that $\lvert B\rvert \gt \lvert A\rvert$ will continue to be true for all $N \gt 1000$.

Thx for your answer. You use $n$ in two different ways, isn't it? I don't understand your last statement "Since ($25^2 = 625) < (2^{10} = 1024)$....". Can you explain it a bit further please?

@PimDumans You're welcome. Yes, I used $n$ for the exponent of $2$ and also the Wikipedia quote uses $n$. I'm sorry for that confusion. To avoid that duplication, I've changed my use of $n$ to $m$ instead. Also, regarding the "Since $(25^2=625)\lt(2^{10}=1024)$...", I was just trying to show that the starting point of $1024$ corresponds to a value above the minimum of $n=25$ for Nagura's result. I've now changed it to be more direct, i.e., using $25$ compared to $2^{\frac{10}{2}}=32$ instead. I hope that's more clear. Please let me know if there's anything else I can explain further.

Is it correct if I state that, based on your explanation, $|B|>|A|$ for all $N \ge 625$? Or do I miss the point? And, if so, can we 'lower' 625?

@PimDumans Yes, that's correct. Since the primes $29$ and $31$ are between $25$ and $2^{\frac{10}{2}}=32$, then if $\lvert B\rvert\gt\lvert A\rvert$ at $N=625$ (I haven't calculated this explicitly, but I'm quite sure it's true), we have using just the squares of primes alone means that $\lvert B\rvert\gt\lvert A\rvert$ for all $N\ge 625$. Regarding being able to 'lower' $625$, the lowest bound is definitely smaller, so you can either manually, or more likely with a computer program, determine this smallest actual value, then use this result for all $N\ge 625$.

I checked it numerical. It appears that $|B|>|A|$, for $120 < N < 625$ (or $1024$).

Thx again for you help. I like to share another question with you. I like to send you an e-mail with a certain conjecture similar to the above question. How can I reach you best?

@PimDumans Regarding sharing a similar conjecture with me by e-mail, is there any particular reason why you want to ask me specifically? Otherwise, note that my number theory knowledge is somewhat limited as it wasn't my primary area of study. As such, I suggest you instead ask a new question so that everybody, especially anybody who can possibly do a better job than me, can see it and perhaps provide answers to it.

thx for your answer. No special reason, but I like your answer's which I understand more than the others. I will try to put my conjecture in a new question. Kind regards

Note that $|A_n|$ (the subset of $A$ of elements $\leq n$) will be $\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor-1$ $\approx\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}-1$. Now, we'll look at the smaller subset $B'$ of $B$ consisting of just the powers of $3$, $5$, and $7$. Then the size of $B'_n$ is roughly $\frac{\ln n}{\ln 3}+\frac{\ln n}{\ln 5}+\frac{\ln n}{\ln 7}-3$, by the same argument. But since $\frac1{\ln 3}+\frac1{\ln 5}+\frac1{\ln 7}\gt\frac1{\ln 2}$, we already have $|B'_n|$ asymptotically greater than $|A_n|$; specifically, since $|B'_n|\gt \frac{\ln n}{\ln 3}+\frac{\ln n}{\ln 5}+\frac{\ln n}{\ln 7}-6$ and $|A_n|\lt\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}-1$, as soon as we have $n_0$ such that $\ln n_0(\frac1{\ln 3}+\frac1{\ln 5}+\frac1{\ln 7}-\frac1{\ln 2})\gt 5$ then $|A_n|\lt|B'_n|\leq |B_n|$ for all $n\geq n_0$. A little arithmetic shows that this happens for $n_0=4200$, and below that it's straightforward to do specific calculations.
With a little more work, we can determine the true asymptotic order of $B_n$; by the same argument as above, we have $B_n\approx \sum_{p\lt\sqrt{n}}(\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}-1)$ $\approx \ln n(\sum_{p\lt\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\ln p})-\sqrt{n}$. By this MathOverflow answer, the latter sum is approximately $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln\sqrt{n})^2} \approx \frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln n)^2}$, so the true order of $B_n$ is $\Theta(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n})$.

For sufficently large $N$ there are more powers of 3 and 5 alone than powers of 2 up to $N$. For powers of each prime $p$ we have $M_p$ powers up to $N$:
$M_2\sim\log_2N$
$M_3\sim\log_3N$
$M_5\sim\log_5N$
The sets of prime powers are all dusjoint except for the number $1$, and for any $N$, $\log_3N+\log_5N>1.06\log_2N$.
$N=10^6$ is large enough for this asymptotic effect to hold.
Powers of $2$: $1,2,4,...,524288$ (20)
Powers of $3$ or $5$: $1,3,5,9,...,390625,531441$ (21)
